# Trying to initialize widgets in Android using a separate class, getting a NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, class, nullpointerexception

I am trying to pull logic in my application into a separate class to reuse the logic within my application, and I am not sure if what I want to do is possible.  I understand I need to call the setContentView function in PercentageCalc.java in order to have the values not be null, but is there any way to pass that through in the Keypad class?

The NullPointerException comes in the first line of the Keypad class.

**PercentageCalc.java**

```
Keypad keypad = new Keypad();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.percentage_calc);

    /** Initialize variables for widget handles */
    ...
    keypad.initializeWidgets();
}
```

**Keypad.java**

```
Button button_1, button_2, button_3, button_4, button_5, button_6, button_7, button_8,
        button_9, button_0, button_clr, button_del, button_period;

public void initializeWidgets()
{
    button_1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b_1);
    button_2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b_2);
    button_3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b_3);
    button_4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b_4);
    button_5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b_5);
    button_6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b_6);
    button_7 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b_7);
    button_8 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b_8);
    button_9 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b_9);
    button_clr = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b_clr);
    button_0 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b_0);
    button_del = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b_del);
    button_period = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b_period);
}
```

Comment: its probably better to initialize the buttons in the activity then pass the buttons to the other class

Comment: LogCat please and specify which line contains the NullPointer

Comment: While debugging, this is the line that contains the NullPointer

`button_1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b_1);`

Comment: Does your Keypad.java extend Activity? If not, then you can't call findViewById on it

Comment: @davefarinelli do you inflate a layout in keypad java file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper approach would be as tyczj mentioned in the comment. But you can pass your main view containing the buttons (R.id.percentage_calc_container in the snippet) to the initializeWidgets() methods in Keypad, and then call findViewById() on it.

**PercentageCalc.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.percentage_calc);

    /** Initialize variables for widget handles */
    ...
    View v = findViewById(R.id.percentage_calc_container);
    keypad.initializeWidgets();
}
```

**Keypad.java**

```
public void initializeWidgets(View v)
{
    button_1 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.b_1);
    button_2 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.b_2);
    button_3 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.b_3);
    button_4 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.b_4);
    button_5 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.b_5);
    button_6 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.b_6);
    button_7 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.b_7);
    button_8 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.b_8);
    button_9 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.b_9);
    button_clr = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.b_clr);
    button_0 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.b_0);
    button_del = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.b_del);
    button_period = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.b_period);
}
```